# Does Apple maintain the security of the built-in Ruby?

Tags: macos, updates, ruby

Does Apple maintain the security of the Ruby implementation that comes by default in OS X?

I recently heard about [CVE-2013-4073](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/27/hostname-check-bypassing-vulnerability-in-openssl-client-cve-2013-4073/), but when I ran "Software Update..." on my OS X Lion box, it didn't update Ruby. Also, I've never noticed a Software Update that changed the Ruby that OS X supplies.

I checked the version of Ruby, and it was prior to patchlevel 374

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

If Apple doesn't do security updates for the built-in Ruby, does that mean that it's a potential security risk, for example if a careless user decided to use it for programming-related tasks?

Comment: This specific issue "only" leads to vulnerabilities in applications that rely on TLS. So if it's only used for other stuff this one won't bite you.

Comment: Sure,Yah its lead to serious security risk .Recently i checked the internet and found that there are some exploits for Ruby 1.8.7 .. See [This link](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-7252/product_id-12215/version_id-60323/Ruby-lang-Ruby-1.8.7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do provide security fixes relating to Ruby - for example the fairly recent [Security Update 2013-002](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5784) includes some Ruby stuff, as did 2013-001. They don't seem to have patched CVE-2013-4073 yet, but to be fair that vulnerability is only a couple of weeks old.

As you imply in your question, the non-careless developer will never try and run a production web app with built-in stack components, but will download and install a separate copy somewhere else and keep that patched and updated appropriately. For one thing, they're very likely to want something more modern than 1.8.7!